# How to upload a picture using feathers.js and multer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, feathersjs

I'm working with feathers.js on the back-end and React on the front end and I need to implement a way to upload a picture. I'm using [multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer) to handle the upload (and I've tried using busboy as well), but I can't seem to get the actual picture uploaded, or at least access it on `req.file`.

On the client side I have:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/picture/upload">
  <input type="file" name="avatar" />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

In `/src/middleware/index.js` I have:

```
'use strict';

const uploadPicture = require('./uploadPicture');

const handler = require('feathers-errors/handler');
const notFound = require('./not-found-handler');
const logger = require('./logger');
var multer = require('multer');
const upload = multer({ dest: '../../client/img'});

module.exports = function() {
  // Add your custom middleware here. Remember, that
  // just like Express the order matters, so error
  // handling middleware should go last.

  const app = this;

  app.post('/picture/upload', upload.single('avatar'), uploadPicture(app));
  app.use(notFound());
  app.use(logger(app));
  app.use(handler());
};
```

This is `src/middleware/uploadPicture.js`:

```
'use strict';

module.exports = function(app) {
  return function(req, res, next) {
    console.log('req.file', req.file);
    console.log('req.body', req.body);

  };
};
```

`req.file` is always undefined, and `req.body` does contain the name of the image I uploaded.

I have tried using mutler and busboy on a basic Express project for testing, and it works perfectly, so that makes me think that maybe it has something to do with the middleware feathers.js uses and probably it changes some header or something, so multer can't append the file to the request object.

This is the order in which middleware is defined in `src/app.js`, which is where the server instance is run:

```
app.use(compress())
  .options('*', cors())
  .use(cors())
  .use('/', serveStatic( app.get('client') ))
  .use(bodyParser.json())
  .use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
  .configure(hooks())
  .configure(rest())
  .configure(services)
  .configure(middleware);
```

Any thoughts on how to handle the image upload in this scenario?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How upload image with feathersjs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47174807/how-upload-image-with-feathersjs)

Comment: @BinUry Different problem, this question has been answered, and this question is way older.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using react, so `enctype` is not a  [supported HTML attribute](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/dom-elements.html#all-supported-html-attributes). I should have used `encType` in my form. That fixed the problem.