# How upload image with feathersjs?

Tags: feathersjs

I have a for User Signup. I'm doing this:

```
 app.service('users').create(
   {
      email:  this.state.Username,
      Nom: this.state.Name,
      Image: "../image/p.png",
   })
```

I am succeeded to add the user to the database. Now, I want to upload an image in the "image" folder and save its path in the attribute "Image". How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [tutorial given in FeathersJS's official documentation to upload a file](https://github.com/feathersjs/docs/blob/master/guides/advanced/file-uploading.md). You can follow this tutorial to upload your image file.

However, you can upload your image file through a separate request using the **uploads** service, shown in the tutorial, and as a response, you will receive the filename saved in the specified folder. Something like this:

```
{
   "id":"6454364d8facd7a88e627e9329ffc2b7a5c879dc838.jpeg",
   "uri": "the-same-uri-we-uploaded",
   "size": 1156
}
```

Here, the "id" is the filename.

Then you can attach this file name to the user object as:

```
{
   email:  this.state.Username,
   Nom: this.state.Name,
   Image: "6454364d8facd7a88e627e9329ffc2b7a5c879dc838.jpeg",
}
```

and save it using the **users** service or whatever you are already using to save the user.

Also, if you want to do it in a single request, then submit the file and user data to **users** service and in a [before hook](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/hooks.html) call the **uploads** service, save the file and attach this data in the user object, so that the **users** service can save it.

Also, remember to save your images in **public/images** folder so that they can be accessed like: *your-domain.com/images/6454364d8facd7a88e627e9329ffc2b7a5c879dc838.jpeg*.

Comment: Thank you for your help , I understand from your answer that I need to store the response of uploads service and then I assign it to the Image attribute . Now if I use the hooks to do it in a single request , I don't understand how get the answer of uploads service . Sorry may be silly question .

Comment: I think you should go with the first one (doing it in separate requests). I'm not sure if the latter solution can be done properly with 'multipart/form-data'. But if you are implementing it by sending directly the Base64 image data, it should work. You should see this: https://github.com/feathersjs/feathers/issues/382#issuecomment-238112819 to understand how to call a service from hook.

Comment: Okay thank you , I will try it in a separate requests.

Comment: Please have you an idea about this type error `Cannot read property 'MISSING_PREFIX' of undefined`

Comment: Where is this error showing? In upload image request?

Comment: Great. Glad you figured it out. :)